# I'm trying to remove " .RETCH " from my file names with my batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename

I'm simply trying to have my existing script remove " .RETCH " from the file name.

ex. " B00TI8DTJY.RETCH.PT01.jpg     -->     B00TI8DTJY.PT01.jpg "

I know how to remove a certain amount of characters or add something to the file name but can't figure out how to Only remove the .RETCH part.

Thanks.

Comment: If you split the file name up by periods, will it always be in the second position?

Comment: Here is what I was trying

 " rename C:\Users\???.RETCH.????.jpg ???.????.jpg "

But if course all that does is remove 4 characters -> ???.RETC.jpg

Comment: That doesn't even remotely answer my question. Will there always be only one `.` to the left of RETCH?

Comment: Sorry..  At work and read that in a hurry, didn't notice the ? mark and took it as a suggestion..    

 .. it will always be" ??????????. RETCH.????.jpg" one period before RETCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir *RETCH* /b') do (
 set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.RETCH=!"
 ren "%%a" "!name!"
)
```

Just run this on the same directory as your files. If it's needed to go on subdirectories then add `/s` flag to `dir` command.

Comment: I can't get this to work. It says it's not recognized as an internal or external command..   I replaced "dir" with my directory then moved everything onto the same line inside the parentheses and I tried it exactly how it's shown above on 4 separate lines. .. 
My file name is  " B00TI8DTJY.RETCH.PT01 "

Comment: Oh I noticed there's a typo here.. I wrote `*RECTCH*` instead of `*RETCH*`, check the edit, does this work now?

Comment: No, I caught that and removed it.. I tried it in a batch by itself in the target directory and as a Choice Command in my script, which is how I intend to use it, and neither would work. I tried exactly as above with changing my directory and RETCH, then I tried it backing everything up to one line inside the parenthesis. Notta..

Comment: Try the exactly code above, `dir` is the command to list the files, so don't replace it. And don't replace `*RETCH*`. Just keep as it is, place the script on the same directory as your file is, and run it.

Comment: O, well that totally worked!! Thank you very much.  I do need to be able to set it to this specific directory " C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\ "  Can this be tweaked for a specific directory without having to run from within said directory? 

And gain, thanks!!