# batch script to rename part of file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I am trying to create a fairly simple (at least I thought) script to rename part of file's extension.  Example:

```
ren C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\*.TESTJPG C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\*.JPG
```

I need it to keep the filename, and keep the last part of the extension.  Is this possible?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
ren C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\*.TEST??????????? C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\*.???????????
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Can you show us some example file names that you have and what you want them to be?

Answer (score 1):

```
ren C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\*.TESTJPG *.JPG
```

should work. You can't have a directoryname in the new filename.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I [answered a simillar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040920/2938090), the same code can help you too:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir *.test* /b') do (
 set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.test=.!"
 ren "%%a" "!name!"
)
```

Here we are removing the word `.test` from files extensions. All you need here is place this script on the same directory as your files are and run it.